# cordova record audio with media plugin

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins

I am using the cordova media plugin to record user voice and storing it in sdcard of a mobile device. 
Everything is working good, but when recording a new file it is overwriting the file which was previously recorded.

I want to create separate file to be created at each time user record his voice.

Can I get help.

Comment: I don't understand what's the matter. It's really easy to record a new file changing its name (see https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media#quick-example-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the src file name every time as following...

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('counter')){
  localStorage.setItem("counter",0);
}

var counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counter'));

function recordAudio() {
    var src = "myrecording"+counter+".mp3";
    var mediaRec = new Media(src,
        // success callback
        function() {
            console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
            counter++;
            localStorage.setItem("counter",counter);

        },

        // error callback
        function(err) {
            console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
        });

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();
    }
```

Try this it won't override the previous file....happy coding

Comment: If it works fine please give an up vote to my answer